# what language is Yahoo Traffic server made in

Tags: apache, yahoo

I want to know what language is used to make Yahoo Traffic Server which 
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/04/traffic_server_graduates_to_a_fullfledged_project/
which handles lots of data.I could not find on internet any where a way to download and use it at my machines can any one give links to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://trafficserver.apache.org/

Yahoo Traffic Server has been released as an open source project under the name Apache Traffic Server. [It is written in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_Server)

You can [download the source for the current stable release](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/trafficserver/trafficserver-2.0.1.tar.bz2).  Or, [your distribution may have a binary package already available](http://advanced.sortatechie.com/linux-administration/apache-traffic-server-installation-and-basic-installation-on-centos-5-5/)

Comment: thanks for your message and specially the links I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I'm not finding a binary package for ubuntu via google.  Looks like maybe it's being worked on in the unstable branch? http://ftp-master.debian.org/new/trafficserver_2.1.5-unstable-1.html    You'll probably have to install from source.